# Windows 7 customize logininput

Tags: windows-7, input

i´d like to customize my Windows7 "loginscreen-input" (for username).

Before a user loggedin, i´d like to fill in the input for username automatically with the string "test:".

Can someone help me?

Comment: What are you do you try to achieve with this? Please consider giving us more information.

Comment: @Ivan Viktorovic id like to add my domain automatically in front of the username

Comment: Do you change the username freqently? Usually you need only to enter the name once and then its saved.